# Get computers that belong and dont belong to a group

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to use the code below to get a list of computernames that are not a member of a InternetExplorer9 group. It runs without errors but it still is giving me computernames that are a member of InternetExplorer9. Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thank you

```
Get-ADComputer -Property * -Filter * -Server DomainController -SearchBase "OU=City,OU=US,DC=Domain,DC=net"  | where {$_.memberof -notmatch 'InternetExplorer9'} | FT Name, memberof
```

Comment: Maybe is just in your post but 'InternetExplorer 9' is different from 'InternetExplorer9' ..

Comment: Sorry was a typo in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Get-ADComputer -Property * -Filter * -Server DomainController -SearchBase "OU=City,OU=US,DC=Domain,DC=net"  |
 where {-not ($_.memberof -match 'InternetExplorer9')} | FT Name, memberof
```

-match and -notmatch, when used against an array will return all elements of the array that satisfied the test, so

```
$_.memberof -notmatch 'InternetExplorer9'
```

is going to return all of the group memberships that don't match 'InternetExplorer9'.  When used as a Boolean test that means it will be true if there are any groups that didn't match.

Where-Object will run the current pipeline object through the Where clause/scriptblock and evaluate the result as Boolean (True/False).  Assume you have 3 groups in your MemeberOf collection:

```
$groups = @('InternetExplorer9','SomeOtherGroup1','SomeOtherGroup2')
 $groups -notmatch 'InternetExplorer9'

SomeOtherGroup1
SomeOtherGroup2
```

The `-notmatch` returned all of the group memberships that did not match 'InternetExplorer9'.  When that is evaluated as a Boolean, it's going to be True, because it found groups that did not match 'InternetExplorer9', and the object will have passed the test and continue on down the pipeline, even though it's a member of the 'InternetExplorer9' group.  The only time it will fail is if ALL of it's group memberships do match 'InternetExplorer9', and the `-notmatch` returns nothing.

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure why but it is returning computers with and without InternetExplorer 9?

Comment: Because it's always finding a group in their .memberof that doesn't match 'InternetExplorer9'.  If it finds at least one, then the test returns True.